# Android studio and R class

Tags: android, layout, r.java-file

I've a little problem with android studio. Until yesterday I used Eclipse. But today I start to use Android studio. I write a simple layout without errors. Than in src/main/java I write this simple code:

```
public class MyActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(android.R.layout.activity_my);
    }
}
```

But I've an arror: "cannot resolve symbol activity_my"

According to me the layout isn't registrated in R.java. How can I resolve this problem? Thanks in advance :D

p.s. sorry for my bad english >.<

Comment: Change `android.R.layout.activity_my` to `R.layout.activity_my` and import  R file

Answer (score 1):

Use `R` and not `android.R`. Check that the imported `R` is `your.package.name.R`.

Comment: Oh my god, stupid problem -.-", sorry guys, and thanks

Answer (score 1):

you should always use `setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);`.

so replace `setContentView(android.R.layout.activity_my);` with `setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);`

USE `CTR + SHIFT + o` to organize your import statements in eclipse.